# Converting SSH command to a PuTTY command

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to translate the SSH command:

```
ssh -N -L 1521:server1.com:1521 username@server2.com
```

into PuTTY.

- `-N`: Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).
- `-L` *[bind_address:]port:host:hostport*: Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.

The command first SSH to `user_name@server2.com`, which in turn connect to `server1` so that it fowarrds port 1521 (server behind NAT).

In a more abstract way, the command [could be written as](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/100859/16704):

```
ssh -L MY_LOCAL_PORT:FOREIGN_ADDRESS:FOREIGN_PORT MYUSER@SSH_SERVER
```

---

I tried to write the following PuTTY command:

```
putty -N -D 1521 -P 1521 server2.com username@server1.com
```

with:

- `-N`: suppress starting a shell or command.
- `-D`: set up SOCKS-based dynamic port forwarding on a local port.
- `-P`: specify a port number

according to the [PuTTY manual](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html).

However I get:

[image]

What could be the issue?

I disabled the firewall, and checked that `putty.exe` allowed to communicate with Internet.

---

Using the PuTTY GUI, the tunnel works with the following configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If all you need is just forward port - you can use plink 'plink -ssh -N -L 1521:server1.com:1521 username@server2.com'

Comment: ... or you could install Cygwin and use OpenSSH like you normally would. ;)

Comment: @n.st Thanks, sure, actually there is an [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/), and their ssh.exe works fine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to translate the SSH command `ssh -N -L 1521:server1.com:1521 username@server2.com` into PuTTY.

If all you need is just forwarding port - you can use plink instead

```
> plink.exe -ssh -N -L 1521:server1.com:1521 username@server2.com
```

> I'd curious how to fix the putty.exe command as well

the same things

```
> G:\putty.exe -ssh -P 2222 -N -L :2222:192.168.88.130:2222 root@node1.example.net -i C:\Users\ALex\.ssh\node1.ppk
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, +1 that works. (I'd curious how to fix the putty.exe command as well)

Answer (score 1):

Putty requires the protocol to be mentioned as well. Since you are using ssh, add 
'-ssh' option as well. You can refer the following link :

[putty command line options](http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/faqs/others/putty/PuTTY%20Command%20Line%20Options.txt)

So a simple command would look like:

```
putty.exe -ssh -P 22 admin@server
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have shell access on server2, and I just want to tunnel through it. I tried `putty -ssh -N -D 1521 -P 1521 server2.com username@server1.com`, it didn't work either.
`

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with your ability/inability to assign a port on the local computer. Try running puTTy with administrative privileges on your local machine.

Comment: On windows you don't need any additional privileges to bind ports > 1024